# Recursively copying directories with a given name

Tags: rsync, recursive

With a directory structure built using

```
#!/bin/bash
for name in A B
do
    mkdir -p /tmp/src/${name}/copyme
    echo "do not copy" > /tmp/src/${name}/no.txt
    echo "copy" > /tmp/src/${name}/copyme/yes.txt
done
```

I would like to mirror just the `copyme` directories, along with the files within them, to /tmp/tgt.

This should be simple. Relying on `rsync` distinguishing the order of the command-line options: exclude everything, then include the relevant pattern. Yet

```
rsync -av --exclude='*' --include='copyme' /tmp/src/ /tmp/tgt/
```

excludes everything (only the target directory is created). Why?

Comment: So, what does "doesn't work" mean here? What exactly happens?

Comment: You'd probably have to `--include='copyme/*'` in addtion to the existing `--include`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `rsync` runs, it tests the found names at the source against the patterns, and the first matching pattern takes effect:

```
$ rsync -avv --exclude='*' --include='copyme' /tmp/src/ /tmp/tgt/
sending incremental file list
[sender] hiding directory A because of pattern *
[sender] hiding directory B because of pattern *
delta-transmission disabled for local transfer or --whole-file
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0

sent 51 bytes  received 86 bytes  274.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

When a directory has been excluded (see "hiding directory..." above), its content is not further considered. Reversing the exclusion and inclusion patterns will not help since it will never get to the `copyme` directories.

The `rsync` manual says:

> For instance, to include `/foo/bar/baz`, the directories `/foo` and
>          `/foo/bar` must not be excluded.  Excluding one of those parent
>          directories prevents the examination of its content, cutting off
>          `rsync`'s recursion into those paths and rendering the include for
>          `/foo/bar/baz` ineffectual (since `rsync` can't match something it never
>          sees in the cut-off section of the directory hierarchy).

So, instead:

```
$ rsync -avv --include='[AB]' --include='copyme/***' --exclude='*' /tmp/src/ /tmp/tgt/
sending incremental file list
[sender] showing directory A because of pattern [AB]
[sender] showing directory B because of pattern [AB]
[sender] showing directory A/copyme because of pattern copyme/***
[sender] hiding file A/no.txt because of pattern *
[sender] showing file A/copyme/yes.txt because of pattern copyme/***
[sender] showing directory B/copyme because of pattern copyme/***
[sender] hiding file B/no.txt because of pattern *
[sender] showing file B/copyme/yes.txt because of pattern copyme/***
created directory /tmp/tgt
delta-transmission disabled for local transfer or --whole-file
./
A/
A/copyme/
A/copyme/yes.txt
B/
B/copyme/
B/copyme/yes.txt
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=10

sent 305 bytes  received 175 bytes  960.00 bytes/sec
total size is 10  speedup is 0.02
```

Note that the exclusion has to come last, after the inclusions.  The `copyme/***` pattern matches both the `copyme` directory name itself and any pathname underneath it.

If you don't want to hardcode the `A` and `B` directory names:

```
for dir in /tmp/src/*; do
    [ ! -d "$dir" ] && continue
    rsync -avv --include="${dir##*/}" --include='copyme/***' --exclude='*' /tmp/src/ /tmp/tgt/
done
```

This would output

```
sending incremental file list
[sender] showing directory A because of pattern A
[sender] hiding directory B because of pattern *
[sender] showing directory A/copyme because of pattern copyme/***
[sender] hiding file A/no.txt because of pattern *
[sender] showing file A/copyme/yes.txt because of pattern copyme/***
created directory /tmp/tgt
delta-transmission disabled for local transfer or --whole-file
./
A/
A/copyme/
A/copyme/yes.txt
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=5

sent 180 bytes  received 148 bytes  656.00 bytes/sec
total size is 5  speedup is 0.02
sending incremental file list
[sender] hiding directory A because of pattern *
[sender] showing directory B because of pattern B
[sender] showing directory B/copyme because of pattern copyme/***
[sender] hiding file B/no.txt because of pattern *
[sender] showing file B/copyme/yes.txt because of pattern copyme/***
delta-transmission disabled for local transfer or --whole-file
B/
B/copyme/
B/copyme/yes.txt
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=5

sent 180 bytes  received 117 bytes  594.00 bytes/sec
total size is 5  speedup is 0.02
```

The result would be

```
$ tree src tgt
src
|-- A
|   |-- copyme
|   |   `-- yes.txt
|   `-- no.txt
`-- B
    |-- copyme
    |   `-- yes.txt
    `-- no.txt

4 directories, 4 files
tgt
|-- A
|   `-- copyme
|       `-- yes.txt
`-- B
    `-- copyme
        `-- yes.txt

4 directories, 2 files
```

---

Another approach which does not use exclusion or inclusion patterns with `rsync` but that uses `find` to locate the `copyme` directories and then `rsync` to copy them:

```
find /tmp/src -type d -name 'copyme' -prune -exec sh -c '
    cd /tmp/src && rsync -aRvv "${1#/tmp/src/}/" /tmp/tgt/' sh {} ';'
```

Notice the `-R` (`--relative`) flag used with `rsync` here.

The `sh -c` script executed for each found `copyme` directory does a `cd` to `/tmp/src` and then copies the pathname with the initial `/tmp/src` bit of its path removed.

The `-prune` in the `find` command stops `find` from looking for further `copyme` directories inside the found directory.

Comment: Very nice. But A and B have no special significance. Consider the case of copying all `__pycache__` subdirectories and the files that are within, yet exclude everything else. How can I then avoid the explicit dependence on naming the A and B subdirectories (in [AB]) and depend instead on an equivalent of all?

Comment: @Calaf I _believe_ I showed this at the very end of the answer (using `find`), but also with the preceding shell loop. The shell loop will only work if the `copyme` directories are located immediately below `/tmp/src/*` though, as in your example.

Comment: The for loop (`for dir in /tmp/src/*; do`) comes closest. Yet `for dir in /path/*` leaves me with a lingering feeling that I must be able to put `/path/*` in a directory, then operate on that directory and get rid of the loop. (My own loop has no special significance, other than populating the files/directories briefly.)